# Remove single pixel gap between child and parent div

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple block of code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 75vw;
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #999;
}
</style>

<center>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</center>
```

But, the results are different when viewed in different screen widths.

Here, the child div completely fits the parent div at a certain screen width.

[image]

But here, when at a different screen width, a white space of about 1px appears on both the sides of the child div.

[image]

How can I get rid of this white space and make sure that the child div completely fits the parent div?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue with the code you have given, it may just be how your browser is rendering it. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Dexterians it's present in chrome and firefox. It depends if you've added a doctype declaration or not. I've fixed it with `box-sizing`.

Comment: @Dexterians I am using Chrome.

Comment: @learningtoanimate yes I saw your answer and upvoted. I didn't think about the ``border-box`` property!

Comment: Haha thank you. It's a common one that I wish was handled the same way quirks mode does by default to save headaches like these.

Answer (score 3):

The issue lies with the border you've used and the way browsers handle this. Setting the `box-sizing` to `border-box` solves this issue. It's a common one but once you know it you'll be able to better spot it.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 75vw;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Also, you don't need to define `text/css` in your tags these days, browsers know what the code is. Also try not to use it inline unless it was just for this question. Similarly, the `<center>` tag has been depreciated which means it's no longer supported in HTML 5 so you should center things using margin or flex. Margin is the easiest so that's why I've added that here.

Sometimes browsers will treat things differently in quirks mode too, so make sure you have a `doctype` declaration.

Comment: There is still a white space on the right side in this snippet.

Comment: Have you got zooming happening? Ie; pages are 110% larger or smaller?

Comment: That's because of how SO snippets runs it (in quirks) if you run it in your own code software or on a live server with doctype declaration you'll see there's no border. Even if you click run and then `Full Page`, it's fine.

Comment: Make sure you have your browser set to 100% viewing; as sometimes scaling can cause funny things in pages too and I'm able to replicate your issue when I zoom at 125%

Comment: I've just ran it on a live server and in localhost preview. No issues with any zoom level for me @Dexterians.

Comment: It's fine here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHA30S4F7XET @KobayakiTunnel. Check your zoom is at 100% and that you have a doctype declaration.

Comment: Depending on zoom level, it can either overlap in to the border sometimes, or as per @KobayakiTunnel's issue, it can produce little white lines. I definitely don't think it's a code issue as much as it is an OS/Browser rendering issue. On the snippet above; If I zoom out to 90% the grey overlaps the border, if I zoom in 125% I see the white lines.

Comment: It's not best practice to remove unaccept a correct answer just because you can't make it work in your own code.

Comment: Sure it is, @learningtoanimate. If the asker can't make it work, then it's not the most helpful answer.

Comment: That's not always true @CodyGray. I've accepted answers I know to be right in the past even if I couldn't make them work with a fuller body of code. It's about the principle in the answer.

Comment: No, it's not. The definition of accepted answer is "the one that the asker found to be the most useful". That's it. There is no other criteria or anything else implied. You can choose to accept an answer or not accept an answer for any reasons you like, as long as you're the one who originally asked the question. There is no obligation to accept any answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using Chrome browser.
I have the same behavior with the very simple code:

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item-a">item A</div>
        </div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.item-a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 3px solid crimson;
}
```

At 100% zoom it has a gap. When I zoom, the gap disappears, but when I zoom again - the gap between *container* and *item-a*  may or may not show up again (you can notice cornflower background of 1px between a parent and child borders).
This is how Google Chrome handles things in both Linux and Windows 11 at the moment.
Then I gave a shot to view the same code via Firefox and there is no gap regardless of zooming.
[image: difference.png]

Comment: Is this something there's a fix for yet?

Comment: @learningtoanimate I had some success removing the border of the outer box. I simulate a border by having a wrapper div with `padding: 2px` instead, this does not create gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the many answers suggesting to set `box-sizing: border-box`, I used content-box instead and it fixed my issue: `box-sizing: content-box`

Comment: But the solution is limited ... if I zoom in using the browser zoom then I can see the issue happening again

Answer (score -1):

Try set child with the same width: 75vw;

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 75vw;
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
.child {
    width: 75vw;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</center>
```